# How to get all publisher or subscriber or stream from a session ?

Tags: opentok

I want to get all publisher or subscriber or stream object from a session object, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

As Fran mentioned, there is no API that exposes all of the streams in a session so you would have to store that data locally. You can do this by listening to the `streamCreated` and `streamDestroyed` events on the client side or by using the [session monitoring](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/) feature on the server side. Session monitoring allows you to receive the following events via a webhook:

- `connectionCreated`
- `connectionDestroyed`
- `streamCreated`
- `streamDestroyed`

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no API to retrieve publishers or subscribers data. You can get session information and streams:

https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#get-stream-info